# edit the values of a database row that are displayed in textboxes

Tags: sql, wpf, sqlconnection

New to WPF. I want to edit the values of a database row that are displayed in textboxes. At the moment I am getting an error: "ExecuteNonQuery:Connection property has not been initialized". When I remove the where clause all rows are updated and not just the selected item.

```
private void btnEDIT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sc.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Rewards set Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "', Cost= '" + this.txtCost.Text + "'where Name = '" + this.txtName.Text +"'");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Update Successfull");
        sc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed you are updating Name field and you are passing same field in the where clause having same value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't set the [`Connection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.connection.aspx) property of `SqlCommand`. So the command does not know where to connect. Use the [constructor overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/877h0y3a.aspx) from `SqlCommand` or set it separate like this

```
cmd.Connection = sc;
```

Comment: sc.open(); This is calling the connection

Comment: This opens the connection, yes. But wherefrom the SqlCommand should know to use this connection?

Comment: do you know how I can auto refresh a combo box once I click save?

Comment: I can't say without context. Please ask a new question for this completely different problem. It also increases the chance for an answer because all can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Rewards set Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "', Cost= '" + this.txtCost.Text + "'where Name = '" + this.txtName.Text +"'",sc); // add connection here
```

also You should use parametrized queries or Stored Procedures that will prevent SQL Injection attacks.

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Update Rewards set Name = @name, Cost= @cost where Name = @name ,sc);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Convert.ToString(this.txtName.Text)); and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you need :) Copy paste this. Good luck bro! :) If you have question, just ask, I'll answer if I know LOL :)

```
  private void btnEDIT_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        sc.Open();
        sql = "UPDATE REWARDS SET Name = '" + this.txtName.Text + "', Cost= '" + this.txtCost.Text + "'WHERE Name = '" + this.txtName.Text +"'");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Update Successfull");
        sc.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: where does sql and con come from they are not recognised?

Comment: Oh, so sorry!
Add these:
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;